# Class Segmentation Fault 11 Delphi XE7 On Android

Tags: android, delphi, appmethod

I am creating a very basic mobile application with an empty form and a TImage component with a PNG loaded in it. When I deploy the apk to a real device I am getting Class Segmentation Fault 11. The exception is raised by;

```
memmove(Dest, Source, Count);
```

line.

The device is a AML8726-MX Dual Core ARMv7 with NEON CPU.
Android version is 4.1.1.

When I run syscheck on the device, neon, swp, half etc are indicated as YES.

As per the documentation the target requirements are met.

The application is running without any problems on some other tablets like samsung S4, S5 etc ...
Ths problem seems to be hardware or target related but I am not able to figure why it is not working even the target requirements are met.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: What is screen density of image? Maybe to high for your device. Try image with lower density. For me that was reason once.

Comment: Screen density of the device is 1280x800. My image is way smaller than that. But this error is not about the code. Because %90 of the original samples supplied with the XE7 are not working also. Probably hardware related but there should be some undocumented requirements about the target platform I guess...

Comment: unfortunately - although they advertise the daylights out of it - not all android devices are supported : http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Android_Devices_Supported_for_Application_Development